# Show Flutter's SnackBar above a visible Drawer menu?

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I have a `Scaffold` with a simple `Drawer` in which I show a menu where a user can press a button. When this button is pressed I want to display a `SnackBar`, but the SnackBar is always displayed behind the Drawer. Is there some way to show it in front of the Drawer?

The drawer's code looks like:

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.lock_open),
            title: Text('Click Me'),
            onTap: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  content: Text(
                'Test.',
              )));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and it is used directly in the Scaffold:

```
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
        [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

They said Drawer must be on the top of UI under MaterialDesign rules. But if you wanna such behaviour too much you can write own SnackBar.

```
static void showSnackBarAsBottomSheet(BuildContext context, String message) 
{
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierColor: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          try {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          } on Exception {}
        });
        return Container(
            color: Colors.grey.shade800,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Wrap(children: [
              Text(
                message,
                style:
                    GoogleFonts.robotoCondensed().copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              )
            ]));
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

I've solved it by adding one more Scaffold inside Drawer and making its background transparent:

```
return Scaffold(
    drawer: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: MyDrawer(),
    [...]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: Instead of showing the drawer, this just freezes the app (without particular error messages).